# Is there a way to calculate gradients for calculations outside tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning

I have a small fully connected model that outputs 15 numbers, which I would like to put into a text file to replace 15 numbers which already are in that file, so I define my model as

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.keras as ks
inputs = ks.Input(shape=X.shape[1:])
d1 = ks.layers.Dense(100, activation='relu')(inputs)
d2 = ks.layers.Dense(100, activation='relu')(d1)
outputs = ks.layers.Dense(15)(d2)

model = ks.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)

optimizer = ks.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=1e-3)
loss_fn = ks.losses.MeanSquaredError()
```

with a custom training loop:

```
epochs = 2 
for epoch in range(epochs):
    print("\nStart of epoch %d" % (epoch,))

    # Iterate over the batches of the dataset.

    # Open a GradientTape to record the operations run
    # during the forward pass, which enables auto-differentiation.
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:

        # Run the forward pass of the layer.
        # The operations that the layer applies
        # to its inputs are going to be recorded
        # on the GradientTape.
        w = model(X, training=True)  # Logits for this minibatch
        with tape.stop_recording(): 
            w_tmp = w.numpy().flatten()

            g.change_weight(np.arange(699, 714), w_tmp)
    
            y_pred = g.get_xsec()

        # Compute the loss value for this minibatch.
        loss_value = loss_fn(y_pred, y_true)

        # Use the gradient tape to automatically retrieve
        # the gradients of the trainable variables with respect to the loss.
    grads = tape.gradient(loss_value, model.trainable_weights)

    # Run one step of gradient descent by updating
    # the value of the variables to minimize the loss.
    optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, model.trainable_weights))

    # Log every 200 batches.
    print(
        "Training loss at epoch %d: %.4f"
        % (epoch, float(loss_value))
    )   
    #print("Seen so far: %s samples" % ((step + 1) * batch_size))
```

Now, `change_weight()` just takes a list of line numbers and the weights to write at those lines, while `get_xsec()` returns an array, which has been calculated with another program outside of tensorflow (actually outside python).
If I run this code, I obviously get the following error

```
ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable: ['dense/kernel:0', 'dense/bias:0', 'dense_1/kernel:0', 'dense_1/bias:0', 'dense_2/kernel:0', 'dense_2/bias:0'].
```

In the previous code I tried to use `tape.stop_recording()` but without success, is there even a solution to this problem? I also tried looking [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/autodiff#2_did_calculations_outside_of_tensorflow) but without any luck.

Comment: Before asking for a "solution", you should think conceptually, how are gradients through a black box function supposed to be computed? It works inside TensorFlow because most operations support gradient computation (this is the autograd part), but without that support there is not much you can expect or do.

Comment: You can use `tf.custom_gradient` to define gradients for functions. You might be able to combine this with `tf.numpy_function` or `tf.py_function` to wrap the outside-TF operations and get gradients. However, this means you have to derive and implement the gradients of your outside-TF functions yourself. Alternatively, you need to re-implement everything with TF operations. As Dr. Snoopy said, there is no "magical" way to get gradients for arbitrary code.